# How to solve the Sturm Liouville problem $y''-3y'+λy=0$, $y'(0)=0$, $y'(\pi)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi everybody I need to find the values of λ>0 and λ<0 to find the own values, I knowk that in the case λ=0 I obtain the trivial solution, but in the other cases I don`t know what to do, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure about the conditions ?

Comment: yes, they are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases, there is the trivial solution  $y(x)=0$

On the page below it is shown that the only case where non trivial solutions exist is if $\quad \lambda=n^2+\frac{9}{4}\quad$ ($n$ integer) :
$$y(x)=C\:e^{3x/2}\left(-\frac{2n}{3}\cos(nx)+\sin(nx)\right)$$

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!, you help me a lot, so a little question, ... do you recommend some program to resolve this equations?

Comment: Hi Mark ! Sorry, I know no program to recommend to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a non-trivial solution of your equation, then it must be a constant multiple of the solution to
$$
                y''-3y'+\lambda y = 0\\
                y'(0)=0,\;\;\; y(0)=1,
$$
the unique solution of which is
$$
                  y_0(t)=e^{-3t/2}(\cos(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\,t)+C\sin(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\,t))
$$
where $C$ satisfies
$$
          (-3/2)+C\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}=0.
$$
Therefore, there is a non-trivial solution $y$ iff
$$
             y_0(t) = e^{-3t/2}\left[\cos(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\,t)+\frac{3}{2}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\,t)}{\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}}\right]
$$
satisfies
\begin{align}
    0=y_0'(\pi)&=(-3/2)e^{-3\pi/2}\left[\cos(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\,\pi)+\frac{3}{2}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\,\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}}\right]\\
   &+e^{-3\pi/2}\left[-\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\,\pi)
      +\frac{3}{2}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\pi)\right].
\end{align}
The cos terms drop out, and give the equation
$$
    0=(\frac{9}{4}+\lambda-\frac{9}{4})\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}}
$$
Therefore, either $\lambda=0$ or $\sqrt{\lambda-9/4}=\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\cdots$. The above remains correct in the limiting case where $\lambda\rightarrow 9/4$ as well, which means that $\lambda=9/4$ is not a valid solution. So,
$$
                \lambda=\frac{9}{4}+n^2,\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots,\\
                     \mbox{ or } \lambda=0.
$$
The unusual case is $\lambda=0$, which gives rise to the solution
$$
    y(t)=e^{-3t/2}\left[\cosh(3t/2)+\frac{3}{2}\frac{i\sinh(3t/2)}{3i/2}\right]=1.
$$
So the eigenfunctions are $1$ and
$$
           e^{-3t/2}\left[\cos(nt)+\frac{3}{2}\frac{\sin(nt)}{n}\right],\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The corresponding values of $\lambda$ are
$$
              \lambda=0,\frac{9}{4}+1^2,\frac{9}{4}+2^2,\frac{9}{4}+3^2,\cdots.
$$